# Finding the shortest unique substring

Tags: python

I have a name and a list of names. I can guarantee that the selected name is contained by the list of other names.

I'd like to generate the shortest substring of the selected name that is contained only by that name, and not by any of the other names in the data.

```py
>>> names = ['smith','jones','williams','brown','wilson','taylor','johnson','white','martin','anderson']
>>> find_substring('smith', names)
"sm"
>>> find_substring('williams', names)
"ll"
>>> find_substring('taylor', names)
"y"
```

I can probably brute-force this fairly easily, by taking the first letter of the selected name and seeing if it matches any of the names, then iterating through the rest of the letters followed by pairs of letters, etc.

My problem is that my list contains more than ten thousand names and they're fairly long - more similar to book titles. Brute force would take *forever*.

Is there some simple way to efficiently achieve this?

Comment: To be clear, are you looking to do this just once, or do you need to do it for many different names but where the list `names` is fixed?

Comment: Not sure how you mean your brute force, but I'd expect brute force to take less than a second, not "forever".

Comment: How about you do implement your brute-force idea and a benchmark to test whether it really takes "forever"? And if it truly does, we can take that benchmark to also test better solutions.

Comment: I agree with all of @HeapOverflow's points above (deleted old comments and added them as answer below for independent discussion sake if OP is interested).

Comment: williams could also be ia

Answer (score 1):

A variation of a [common suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree) might be enough to achieve this at less than `O(n^2)` time (used in bioinformatics for large genome sequencing), but as @HeapOverflow mentioned in the comments, I do not believe brute forcing this problem would be much of an issue unless you are considering running the algorithm with literally hundreds of millions of strings.

Using the Wikipedia article above for reference: you can built the tree at `O(n)` time (all strings, not individual string), and use it to find all `z` occurences of a string `P` of length `m` in `O(m + z)` time. Implemented right you'll likely be looking at a time of `O(n) + O(am + az) = O(am + az)` time for a list of `a` words (anyone is welcome to double check my math on this).

Comment: I had seen the `<` and it doesn't really help. It's still unclear where the O(n^2) comes from. Is it the complexity used in bioinformatics for large genome sequencing? What role does that play here, i.e., why mention it? O(n^2) is far worse than even any brute force I can think of here.

Comment: Finding all substrings from a string, brute-force method and ensuring order is `O(n^2)`. Finding all substrings (indifferent of order) is `O(2^n)` (powerset). In this case I assume OP means ensuring order.

Comment: Yeah but that string is something like the concatenation of all names, right? Who in their right mind would care about all substrings of that? How is that supposed to help here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best bet would be brute force, however, keep a dictionary of checked letter combinations and whether or not they matched any other names.

```
["s":true, "m": true, "sm": false"]
```

Consulting this list first would help reduce the code of checking against other strings and speed up the method as it runs.